# One hundred breaths exercise

Tags: exercise, exercise-technique, home-exercise, breathing

Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oF_cqp0FLf4) named one hundred breaths exercise. I would like to know what is its sources? Is it Tai Chi? Is there a tutorial that explains how to do it step by step and what is its benefits?